# How can I get this d3 heatmap to show a certain time frame?

Tags: html, d3.js

For reference, I am using the html code from this website. 
http://bl.ocks.org/tjdecke/5558084
I am also using his example .tsv files. 
I am trying to change the heatmap so that the blocks between 1 AM - 7 AM do not show, and my heatmap would show only information between 8AM - 12PM. I have changed the number of hours in the `times` array but this only shifts the hours, while the number of blocks remains the same. I also tried limiting the data to only include those whose value is 8 or higher for "hour", but I get this.

[Attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLnSe.png)

Any ideas on how to fix this? I greatly appreciate your time, as I have been fiddling around for a few hours now but cannot seem to get anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The sample uses 24 columns on the grid, you will have to adjust for the number of columns you want:

```
  var margin = { top: 50, right: 0, bottom: 100, left: 30 },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 430 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      gridSize = Math.floor(width / 24), // Need to change here.
      legendElementWidth = gridSize*2,
```

You might need to change on other places but this at least at starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply For those interested, the fix was on this line of code:

Comment: `cards.enter().append("rect")
              .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.hour - 8) * gridSize; }) //changed from 1 to 8
              .attr("y", function(d) { return (d.day - 1) * gridSize; })
              .attr("rx", 4)
              .attr("ry", 4)`
              .attr("class", "hour bordered")
              .attr("width", gridSize)
              .attr("height", gridSize)
              .style("fill", colors[0]);